# OSMF self start playback after system sleep

Tags: osmf

I have an issue with OSMF player: in case you load a page with video, then send system to sleep - after system wakeup playback starts itself. This is valid if you are using f4m file or rtmp stream. Those issues are visible on OSMF demos:

http://www.osmf.org/dev/1.6gm/StrobeMediaPlayback.html - no issues, but here
http://www.osmf.org/dev/1.6gm/debug.html video starts itself after system wakeup.

It sometimes happen if you just open a browser and leave it for 15-30 mins. Commonly - any Mac or Win7, any chrome/firefox...
Changing source to flv allows to get rid of the issue.
Also, if you load page, than start it and pause it - the issue will not reproduce as well.
Control bar behaves also very strange: playback time and scrollbar are updated according to actual playback, but play button (not pause) is presented. on case i push play - video restarts.
Systems: MacOS (10.7.5, build 11G63), Firefox 20, Chrome 26, Flash (11.7.700.169); Windows 7: Firefox 17, Flash (11.6.602.180); our cluents also mentioned they have same issues on Win8 under Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome.

I guess that is osmf bug, but no help from adobe (http://forums.adobe.com/message/5246796#5246796), maybe someone has an idea?

Answer (score -1):

Try to compile the 2.0 version of Strobe by downloading the [OSMF source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/osmf.adobe/files/OSMF%202.0%20Release%20%28final%20source%2C%20ASDocs%2C%20pdf%20guides%20and%20release%20notes%29/)

I wouldn't spend a lot of time debugging the issue if that doesn't work. Strobe has not gotten any development support in ages and there is certainly things like this lurking around in the source code.

How to compile it has been answered before on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406060/where-is-strobemediaplayback-swf-in-osmf-2-0).

I wouldn't spend a lot of time debugging the issue if that doesn't work. Strobe has not gotten any development support in ages and there is certainly things like this lurking around in the source code.