# Where is StrobeMediaPlayback.swf in OSMF 2.0?

Tags: osmf, strobe-media-playback

I just download the OSMF 2.0 zip on sourceforge ([here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osmf.adobe/files/)) and there is no StrobeMediaPlayback.swf in the folder?

I'm confused. Somebody can enlight me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find it, you will have to build it yourself using Flex builder or the mxmlc application command line compiler for flex.

First install mxmlc as described here: https://github.com/johansyd/flex-installer

The StrobeMediaPlayback source is found in: ./OSMF/player/StrobeMediaPlayback

```
cd OSMF/player/StrobeMediaPlayback
```

download the OSMF.swc and place it in: OSMF/player/StrobeMediaPlayback/libs

Then do:

```
mxmlc src/StrobeMediaPlayback.as -library-path+=libs -library-path+=assets -sp="src/" -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true -o bin-debug/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf -swf-version=11 -debug=false  -default-script-limits 1000 60 -define CONFIG::LOGGING false -define CONFIG::FLASH_10_1 true
```

You should then have a StrobeMediaPlayback.swf you can use.